# How to give entry in the where clause when we use it in webpages?

Tags: sql, html, database, jsp

According to the user's input I want to select the record from the database. This is my code:

```
<%
String jempid=request.getParameter("empid");
out.println(jempid);
int intempid=1223;
Connection conn=null;
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from empdetails where empnum=jempid");
%>
```

It throws the following error

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'jempid' in 'where clause

Comment: he he .. no code is perfect code.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad idea to construct SQL using string concatenation - you're just opening yourself up to a SQL injection attack -- ESPECIALLY considering that you're getting the value of "empid" directly from the request.  Yikes!

A better approach is use a parametrized query such as below:

```
PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement("select * from empdetails where empnum=?");
st.setString(1, jempid);
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
```

Also you should check that jempid is not null.

Comment: Good to encompass all cases, but really the only problem here was that he forgot to make jempID a variable.  This much effort might further confuse one who wrote the original code.

Comment: @Chris, right - but other developers who come here can always learn other ways of doing this.

Comment: If someone asks you "Hey - why can't I shoot myself in the foot?" -- do you cock the gun or take it away from them?

Comment: Okay maybe a bad analogy, but @Shivasubramanian basically said it - if someone is reading this page either to copy/paste code or (hopefully) to learn, I'd rather have them learn the proper way to construct SQL than just concatenating strings.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your select statement:

```
select * from empdetails where empnum=jempid
```

jempid is hardcoded instead of being used as a variable.  This will never work unless you change it to the variable value entered by the customer.

alter to:

```
"select * from empdetails where empnum=" + CleanseUserInput(jempid)
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: And this is a prime example why you shouldn't cover everything in an answer, @rbobby. What if the jempid were a string? That would require quotes. Better to answer the question at hand rather than trying to cover all bases.

Comment: @Pax, good point, but devs are notoriously bad for allowing for sql injection attacks.

Comment: Still, one up on my answer (and I don't like those new-fangled high-falutin' parameterized queries :-), so +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like too much code in a jsp page....
that said:

```
... empnum='"+jempid+"');" ......
```

And also when you are done be sure to close the db too

Comment: Yes, @rbobby, but not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

yes sometimes it throws an error of unkown column say for example we have table bikes

so lets say we have a query like **select * from bikes where bikename=hayabusa;**

if you will hit this query than it might throw an error like unknown column so the best thing you should take care is quote your value ehich you are giving in **where** clause so the correct way goes as **select * from bikes where bikename='hayabusa';**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(
    "select * from empdetails where empnum=" + jempid);
```

You need to put the **value** of jempid into the string, not the **text** "jempid".

Comment: Yes, @rbobby, but not really relevant to the question at hand. We all know you shouldn't allow injection attacks but, if you wanted to cover every way in which an answer was "wrong", they'd all end up being 10,000-word essays.

Comment: You could just as easily say we should have removed the unnecessary code as well such as "int intempid=1223;" :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet 
  rs=st.executeQuery("select * from empdetails where empnum=" + jempid + ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"select * from empdetails where empnum="+jempid
```

But you really want to protect this against SQL injections!

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to other responses, why not use a PreparedStatement?

Basically, you'll have to code like this:

```
PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement("select * from empdetails where empnum=?");
st.setString(1, jempId);
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
```

The reason you should use PreparedStatements is because of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) issues. For example, using the code you posted in the question, a hacker can always type "1;delete * from empdetails" in the textbox from which you select jempid.

Thus the final query formed would be

```
select * from empdetails where empnum=1;delete * from empdetails
```

which would result in all data in empdetails getting deleted.

So always use PreparedStatements!!

Answer (score 0):

`where` should have the input within `" "`. Like this:

```
"select * from empdetails where empnum = "jempid";
```

Hence this should work:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from empdetails where empnum=" +"'"+ jempid+"'");
```